# Pymongo. Get null if the searched data doesn't exist

Tags: python, database, python-3.x, pymongo

I'm trying to search for user_name in mongoDB and if it's found it will print the user_id from the db. And if is not found I want to print "Id not found" but there's a problem: If the user_no_aront is not found then it doesn't print anything. Not even a "null" message. So any way to make the code send a "null"/"None" message if the data I'm asking for is not found?

```
        connection = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://xxx:xxx@xxxx.mlab.com:xxx/xxx")
        ddb = connection['aurora']
        coll = db['users']
        user = ''.join(args)
        user_no_aront = re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', user)
             curs = coll.find({"user_name":user_no_aront}, {"user_id":True, "_id":False})
                for item in curs:
                    get_user = item.get("user_id", None)
                    print("get_user")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if user_no_aront doesn't exist in coll, the for-loop won't get execute at all. that's the reason why you won't print any thing, even None.